# VGA to HDMI Converter

Tags: screen, connectors

I have a VGA screen I want to buy for the raspberry pi. However since the pi 2 only has hdmi I need a converter. Do you think this will [work](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008279OJ6)?  Also is there anyway I could use an RCA screen to connect to the Pi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The adapter you show works (potential quality issues aside as always with cheap ebay cables). If you want to connect an RCA screen - the pi 2 no longer has a dedicated RCA out (the yellow terminal on the pi A/B) but has integrated the RCA video out into the stereo jack. You need [a cable like this](http://www.mcmelectronics.com/product/24-15489) and then you have sound & video out via RCA. You can either buy one, or perhaps you have a camcorder that already came with such a cable - they are commonly used for camcorders and other small video devices.

Answer (score 1):

- cable should be okay, although you won't get audio
- original raspberry pi has rca output, maybe you want to look into that